# How do i edit the plugin files in DataBase via phpMyAdmin?

Tags: plugins, database, phpmyadmin

I need guidance to edit the WordPress plugin and theme files via phpmyadmin

If I want to edit a particular plugin file or remove a plugin completely from database, I could able to find them ,but I can able to find the data tables for options  , comments, links etc.  I don't know how to edit/remove a particular plugin or theme there.

Could anybody let me know how to find a particular plugin or the entire ' plugins ' folder in data base?

Thank you!

Comment: @user391: As Bainternet stated the files for plugins/themes are not stored in the database. If you meant that you need to edit/remove some data stored by a plugin/theme, then it's possible we can help you. However there's no good generic "do-this" list to remove that data; you'd have to provide specifics of the plugin/theme and the data you want to get rid of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugins and themes are no in the database,  they are physical files under wp-content directory, and that is why you CAN'T find them in the database nor edit them from phpmyadmin.

However WordPress has a built in editor for plugins and themes files. For themes its under appearances -> editor and for plugins its under plugins-> editor.

Comment: Thank you Bainternet ! I need help regarding this and will post it shortly